# php mysqli ответ на запрос сервера

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

возвращает

```
[{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 12"},{"name":"????? 12"},{"name":"????? 1"},{"name":"????? 27"},{"name":"????? 1"},{"name":"????? 27"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 1"},{"name":"????? 2"},{"name":"????? 1"},{"name":"????? 2"},{"name":"????? 3"},{"name":"????? 4"},{"name":"????? 5"},{"name":"????? 6"},{"name":"????? 12"},{"name":"????? 12"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 10"},{"name":"????? 9"},{"name":"??? ???"},{"name":"????? 6"},{"name":"????? 12"}]
```

возвращет хоть в phpmyadmin все нормально выводится 2 колонки код функции

```
public function conclusionData()
    {
        $this->_mysqli->query('utf8_general_ci');
        $result=NULL;
        $sql=$this->_mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.name,e.name FROM stat s JOIN episodes e on s.source_id=e.id JOIN anime a on e.anime_id=a.id");
      //  $sql->bind_param("i",$data);
        $status=$sql->execute();
        if($status){
            $result = $sql->get_result ();
            $returnArray=array ();
            $row  =  $result -> fetch_assoc ();
            while ($row) {
                $returnArray[] = $row ;
                $row  =  $result -> fetch_assoc ();
            }
            $result -> free ();
            return json_encode($returnArray);

        }
```

с кодировкой все нормально в бд выстовлена на всех 3 таблицах utf8_general_ci
буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: [Как правильно соединяться с mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

Comment: @Ипатьев Непомогло я уже думаю попробывать сменить всю кодировку

Answer (score 0):

была такая проблема
после подключение к базе нужно выполнить запрос
$this->_mysqli->query('SET NAMES utf8');